# Django filter where model doesn't have a foreign object or foreign field is equal to

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

I have two models `Community` and `UserCommunity`

Community Model

```
class Community(models.Model):

    # Community name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="admins", blank=True
    )
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="admins", blank=True
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="members",
        blank=True,
    )
    ------
```

UserCommunityModel

```
class UserCommunity(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="user"
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Community, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="group")
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    # True is in community, false is not in community
    active = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to get all the community objects where a user is not part of the community and the community should have at least 1 member

I've tried using this

```
Community.objects.filter(group__user=request.user.id, group__active=False,state=location.state, group_discoverability="public").exclude(
        hofAdmins__isnull=True, admins__isnull=True, members__isnull=True)[:10]
```

But this returns the communities which has a UserCommunity object, UserCommunity object is created when user joins the community.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Community.objects.filter(~Q(members__in=[request.user.id]), ~Q(hofAdmins__in=[request.user.id]), ~Q(admins__in=[request.user.id]), state=location.state, group_discoverability="public").exclude(         hofAdmins__isnull=True, admins__isnull=True, members__isnull=True)[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with:

```
Community.objects.exclude(
    group__user=request.user,
    group__active=True
).exclude(
    mebers=request.user
).exclude(
    admins=request.user
)
```

This will thus exclude a `Community` from the moment there is a `UserCommunity` with `active=True`, and `user=request.user`.

or when the community should have at least one member:

```
Community.objects.filter(
    group__active=True
).exclude(
    group__user=request.user,
    group__active=True
).exclude(
    mebers=request.user
).exclude(
    admins=request.user
).distinct()
```

I would also advise to remove the many `ManyToManyField`s: your `UserCommunity` already is the [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) between the user model and the `Community`. You can add a field `role` for example to disambiguate between members and admins. By making multiple many-to-many tables, the query will be less efficient and annotating will be more cumbersome.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `Community`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`admins`</s> relation to `admin_communities`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I will make the correction to the related name. The above query gives me the results of the communities user is not part of. I edited the post, there is an additional filter where the community should have at least one member i.e ```hofAdmins__isnull=True, admins__isnull=True, members__isnull=True```

Comment: Thank you, will try it out! Yes I realized while working right now, that the many to many field is making redundant data. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Hi, ```group__isnull=False``` still returns groups with 0 members as I joined a group 1 UserCommunity object was created and active=True, when I left active becomes False but the object exists.

Comment: @AbhishekAN: ah yes, you should add `group__active=True` to take the status into consideration.

Comment: Adding `group_active=True` shows me groups that I've never joined i.e only groups without a UserCommunity object

Comment: This query gives me the desired result ```Community.objects.filter(~Q(members__in=[request.user.id]), ~Q(hofAdmins__in=[request.user.id]), ~Q(admins__in=[request.user.id]), state=location.state, group_discoverability="public").exclude(
        hofAdmins__isnull=True, admins__isnull=True, members__isnull=True)[:10]```